# Delete a set of panels with UserControls created in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, loops, panel

I created a panel with a button "add" and a button "delete". If you click on "add" a panel is created right below this header, you can create as much as you want, they are listed.

On each panel there is a checkbox and I would like to delete the panel if the checkbox is checked once the button delete is clicked.

I can get the intuition of a loop : for, but still too novice to get through this without a little tip.

-

```
public partial class Test_auto : Form
{
    ArrayList strategyFutureList = new ArrayList();

    public Test_auto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }

    //Create a new future strategy
    public void CreateStrategyFuture()
    {
        ConsoleStrategyItem strategyItemFuture = new ConsoleStrategyItem();
        strategyItemFuture.Location = new Point(3, 3);
        futureContainer.Height += 85;
        strategyFutureList.Add(strategyItemFuture);
        futureContainer.Controls.Add(strategyItemFuture);
        ConsoleStrategyItem.Instance.txtStrategyName.Text = "Strat Future " + strategyFutureList.IndexOf(strategyItemFuture) + " ";
        ConsoleStrategyItem.Instance.Name = "strategyFuture" + strategyFutureList.IndexOf(strategyItemFuture);
        ConsoleStrategyItem.Instance.cbxDeleteStrategy.Name = "cbxDeleteFuture" + strategyFutureList.IndexOf(strategyItemFuture);
    }

    //Makes it appear
    private void btnAddStrategyFuture_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateStrategyFuture();
    }

    //Delete a-some selected strategies
    public void DeleteStrategyFuture()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strategyFutureList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ConsoleStrategyItem.Instance.cbxDeleteStrategy.Checked = true)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnDeleteStrategyFuture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteStrategyFuture();
    }
}
```

Comment: If can't see where are you adding the controls to the form. You are just adding them to an ArrayList

Comment: my mistake... thank you I corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to create a separate ArrayList to maintain the list of UserControls being added to the `futureContainer`, you can simply iterate through the Controls collection of it.

simply do this in your `DeleteStrategyFuture()` method

```
public void DeleteStrategyFuture()
{
    var length=futureContainer.Controls.Count;
    foreach(int i=0; i< length; i++)
    {
        if(futureContainer.Controls[i].GetType()==typeof(ConsoleStrategyItem))
        { 
           bool isChecked =((ConsoleStrategyItem)futureContainer.Controls[i])
                               .Instance.cbxDeleteStrategy.Checked;
           if(isChecked)
           {
               futureContainers.Controls.Remove(futureContainers.Controls[i]);
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The panel to delete is : strategyItemFuture, not futureContainer which contained all the strategies

Comment: And I  can't find out why I cannot instance strategyItemFuture

Comment: the idea is you should remove the control from the parent container in which you are adding all by finding it. code shows you that

Comment: Ok, but : bool isChecked = ((ConsoleStrategyItem)futureContainer.Control[i]).Instance.cbxDeleteStrategy.Checked; if (isChecked)
the instance does not work

Comment: Should i create a new instance ?